# How to stop FileNotFoundException from popping up?

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

So I'm trying to find the two closest pairs in a text file and then find how close they are. I have most of it worked out but for some reason whenever I try to run the code the file not found exception keeps popping up. I can't seem to get it to run the actual code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;

/**
 *
 * @author birnbook
 */
public class ClosestPair {
  
    public static void ClosePair() { // string compare
    try{
        File text = new File("/Lab2%20Output.txt");
        double temp = 0;
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        double stormag = 0;
        
        // scanning the file in
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(text);
        int lines = 0;
        while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {
            lines++;
        }
        Scanner scnnr = new Scanner(text);
        double[] arr = new double[lines];
        while (scnnr.hasNextLine()) {
            String num = scnnr.nextLine();
            arr[1] = Double.parseDouble(num);
        }
        
        stormag = arr[0] - arr[1];
        if (stormag == 0){
            stormag *= -1;
        }
        for(int i=0; i< arr.length;i++){
            for(int k=1;k< arr.length; k++){
                if(i != k){
                    temp = arr[i] - arr[k];
                    if(temp <= 0){
                        temp *= -1;
                    }
                    if (temp < stormag){
                        stormag = temp;
                        x = arr[i];
                        y = arr[k];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The numbers " + x + " and " + y + "are the closest pair with a difference of " + stormag);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");
    }
 
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    ClosePair();
        
    }    
    
}
```

Comment: Your pathname looks incorrect:  `"/Lab2%20Output.txt"`.  The `%` is used for escaping in a URL, but this is not a URL.  It is a pathname.  So you are asking the OS to open a file with a literal `%20` in it.  You probably mean `"/Lab2 Output.txt"` ; i.e. with a space character instead of `%20`.

Comment: What's the actual name of your file? You seem to be escaping a space as though it was going to appear in a URL. Have you tried `/Lab2 Output.txt`?

Comment: Double check if file you are referring exists in expected path, if file exists, try running it again by passing absolute path and if it works with absolute path, you need fix your relative path of file

Comment: Also it is helpful to provide exception stacktrace along with the code.

Comment: make sure to choose correct file the error you have is here `File text = new File("/Lab2%20Output.txt");`